# What are the performance effects of declaring functions inside functions?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following classes `Test1` and `Test2`. `Test1` declares two functions, `fA` and `fB`, and `fA` is called inside `fB`. `Test2` declares `fA` inside `fB`. Would either of them have a performance advantage over the other? Assume that `fA` is recursive and will be called once every time `fB` is called.

Example:

```
function Test1() {
    this.fA = function() {
        //function body here...
    };

    this.fB = function() {
        //some code...

        this.fA();
    };
};

function Test2() {
    this.fB = function() {
        let fA = function() {
            //function body here...
        };

        //some code...

        fA();
    };
};
```

Comment: Unless the functions are going to be called millions and millions of times the difference is completely ignorable, if there's a difference at all.

Comment: There shouldn't be a notable performance differences if the function definitions are the same.

Comment: [Obligatory link to Eric Lippert on performance](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Note: the example provided is a typical use case for a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes#Modifying_prototypes)

Comment: There are reasons why you would do one over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, `fA` gets created once; in the second, it gets created each time `fB` is called.  So the second is surely slower, but as @Pointy points out, probably not enough to worry about.